# I have requirement to development a registration form, I'm using Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In the Lightning component, I need to use a existing/create custom picklist(Decision Role: Decision Maker,Recommender,Influencer) on opportunity in lightning.

Below is my Component Code

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:appHostable,lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="Opportunity" type="Opportunity" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:600px">
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm"
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                  recordTypeId="{!v.Opportunity}"
                                  objectApiName="Opportunity"
                                  onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}">
            <lightning:messages />
            <div class="slds-text-heading_medium"><b><u>RedHat Deal Registration Information</u></b></div>
             <div class="slds-text-heading_low"><b><u>Customer Information</u></b></div>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="TEST_1__c" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Customer_Email__c" />             


            <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Save" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

And Below is my Controller Code:

```
({
onSuccess: function(component,event,helper){
    //Show Success message on upsertion of record
    var resultToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    resultToast.setParams({
                        "title": "Success!",
                        "message": "Record Saved Successfully"
                    });
    resultToast.fire();
    //Navigate to sObject home page
    var homeEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    homeEvent.setParams({
        "scope": "Opportunity"
    });   

    homeEvent.fire();
}
})
```

**Any Suggestions on How to use a existing picklist on Oppty or create a new picklist field in lightning Component**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add new/ existing pick list field in to`lightning:recordeditform` ex:-if your new/existing picklist fields is `abc_c`  then you need to add `abc__c` field in to your code like below. let me know if you have any issue.

```
<div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:600px">
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm"
                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              recordTypeId="{!v.Opportunity}"
                              objectApiName="Opportunity"
                              onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}">
        <lightning:messages />
        <div class="slds-text-heading_medium"><b><u>RedHat Deal Registration 
       Information</u></b></div>
         <div class="slds-text-heading_low"><b><u>Customer Information</u></b></div>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="TEST_1__c" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Customer_Email__c" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="abc__c" />  // new or existing picklist field             


        <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Save" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</div>
```